# How to find which polygon selected in google maps api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I'm New to Google maps Api , I created polygons in google maps, i want to find out which polygon i clicked, I tried but i'm not able to find out , here is my code

```js
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.9648451,77.5741997),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),  mapOptions);
    var arr = new Array();
    var polygons = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var coordinates = [];

    // downloadUrl("subdivision-coordinates.php", function(data) {
     var xmlString = '<subdivisions><subdivision name="Auburn Hills"><coord lat="12.973111130721453" lng="77.54373550415039"/><coord lat="12.929112653428087" lng="77.53360748291016"/><coord lat="12.936306851970127" lng="77.57635116577148"/></subdivision><subdivision name="Vanderveen"><coord lat="12.97227473026135" lng="77.59489059448242"/><coord lat="12.952200275819832" lng="77.58750915527344"/><coord lat="12.95487696326559" lng="77.60536193847656"/></subdivision></subdivisions>';
        //var xmlString =$('#xml_values').val();
        var xml = xmlParse(xmlString);
        var subdivision = xml.getElementsByTagName("subdivision");
        for (var i = 0; i < subdivision.length; i++) {
            arr = [];
            var coordinates = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("subdivision")[i].getElementsByTagName("coord");
            //console.log("coordinates="+xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("subdivision")[i].getElementsByTagName("coord"));


            for (var j=0; j < coordinates.length; j++) {
              arr.push(new google.maps.LatLng(
                    parseFloat(coordinates[j].getAttribute("lat")),
                    parseFloat(coordinates[j].getAttribute("lng"))
              ));

              bounds.extend(arr[arr.length-1])
              //console.log("arr lenghth="+arr.length+"___"+arr[arr.length-1]+"|___|"+coordinates[j])

            }
            polygons.push(new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: arr,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#FF0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.35
            }));
            polygons[polygons.length-1].setMap(map);

     google.maps.event.addListener(polygons[polygons.length-1], 'click', function (event) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(event));
});


        }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);


function xmlParse(str) {
  if (typeof ActiveXObject != 'undefined' && typeof GetObject != 'undefined') {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  }

  if (typeof DOMParser != 'undefined') {
    return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  }

  return createElement('div', null);
}


}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

How to identify which polygon is clicked using polygon number in google maps api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the polygon, add an additional property to identify the polygon, e.g.

```js
polygons.push(new google.maps.Polygon({
    id: i,
    paths: arr,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
}));
```

Then in your event listener, you should be able to get this from the `this` scope of that polygon:

```js
polygons[polygons.length-1].addListener('click', function (event) {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```